# permission denied to set parameter "client_min_messages" to "notice"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, pgadmin

I have a redshift cluster launched and running on aws and the inbound query is authorized by configuring the VPC security group

Then I try to connect to the redshift with pgAdmin and received following error

```
An error has occurred:
ERROR:  permission denied to set parameter "client_min_messages" to "notice"
```

and

```
An error has occurred:
Column not found in pgSet: "datlastsysoid"
```

Comment: Hi, did you solve the problem? Have any ideas of the reason? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [SQL Workbench](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-using-workbench.html)?

Answer (score 22):

PgAdmin is mainly a Postgres client and is not a supported client for redshift.  Due to its incompatibility, opening a connection always tries to set client_min_messages, but Redshift refuses to accept such a setting. This causes the error you experienced.

Redshift supports only the below parameters which have to be set at the cluster -

```
dev=# show all;
           name            |       setting        
---------------------------+----------------------
 analyze_threshold_percent | 10
 datestyle                 | ISO, MDY
 extra_float_digits        | 0
 query_group               | default
 search_path               | $user, public, admin
 statement_timeout         | 0
 wlm_query_slot_count      | 1
(7 rows)
```

You can use other clients like [psql](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-from-psql.html) or [SQLWorkbench/J](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-using-workbench.html) as pgAdmin has deviations and doesn't support connections to redshift. You can also refer to [this](https://github.com/python-postgres/fe/issues/72) where an issue is reported on Github.